# Using alias name in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, column-alias

I am executing the below query and using alias name for all columns. I have named alias with a . since that is a requirement. now, I want to refer to the alias name directly in the where clause and i do is as given below:

```
SELECT pt.prod_desc AS"PROD_DESC",
 (
CASE
WHEN pt.prod_level='2'
THEN 'Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN 'Sub-Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN 'Service'
ELSE 'N/A'
 END)         AS"PROD_LEVEL",
prod_id      AS "PROD_ID",
isactive     AS "IsActive",
updt_usr_sid AS "UPDT_USR_SID",
updt_ts      AS "UPDT_TS",
(
CASE
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN parent_prod_id
ELSE NULL
  END) AS ".SUB_PROD_ID",
(
 CASE
  WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
  THEN
  (SELECT prod_desc FROM dims_prod_type A WHERE A.prod_id= pt.parent_prod_id
  )
  ELSE 'N/A'
 END ) AS ".SUB_PROD_DESC",
 (
CASE
WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN parent_prod_id
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN
  (SELECT parent_prod_id
  FROM dims_prod_type A
  WHERE A.prod_id= pt.parent_prod_id
   )
 ELSE NULL
   END) AS ".PRNT_PROD_ID",
(
 CASE
 WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN
   (SELECT prod_desc FROM dims_prod_type A WHERE A.prod_id=pt.parent_prod_id
   )
  WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN
   (SELECT prod_desc
   FROM dims_prod_type A
  WHERE A.prod_id IN
    (SELECT B.parent_prod_id
    FROM dims_prod_type B
    WHERE b.prod_id=pt.parent_prod_id
    )
  )
 ELSE 'N/A'
 END)AS ".PRNT_PROD_DESC"
FROM dims_prod_type pt
WHERE pt.".PRNT_PROD_ID" like 'A%';
```

However when i am executing this I get the following error:

```
    SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PT".".PRNT_PROD_ID": invalid identifier
     00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I know that SQL executes the where clause first and hence that is the reason of the error. But how do i fix this? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please format the query so it is more readable.

Comment: Not relevant to the question really, but why is it a requirement to have a `.` in the alias name? In your previous question it was mentioned that it makes it necessary to quote the alias name everywhere and exactly match the case used. I can't think of any reason it would be useful. Just curious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know you [can't use the alias in the `where` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries002.htm#sthref2213), but that only applies in the same level of SQL. You can wrap your query in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT pt.prod_desc AS"PROD_DESC",
  ...
   END)AS ".PRNT_PROD_DESC"
  FROM dims_prod_type pt
)
WHERE ".PRNT_PROD_ID" like 'A%';
```

The only alternative would be to repeat the whole `case` that generates that column in the `where` clause, which would be unpleasant with something so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Put the query in a subquery, then you can refer to the aliases in your where clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pt.prod_desc AS"PROD_DESC",
   ...etc...
  FROM dims_prod_type pt) pt
WHERE pt.".PRNT_PROD_ID" like 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "PT".".PRNT_PROD_ID" by "PT"."PRNT_PROD_ID" or for a better understanding by pt.prnt_prod_id

Comment: This will not work since the where clause will be evaluated first and by that time reference to pt.prnt_prod_id will not exist.